derivative of dyadic eigenvector product of matrix w.r.t matrix
Suppose $\mathbf{B}$ is a real symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrix and its spectral form is given by
$$ \mathbf{B} = \sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i \mathbf{n}_i \otimes  \mathbf{n}_i $$
where $\lambda_i$ and $ \mathbf{n}_i $ are the eigenvalues and unit eigenvectors, respectively. $\otimes$ denotes the dyadic product.
I want to compute the $3^4$ coefficients of
$$ \frac{\partial \mathbf{n}_i \otimes  \mathbf{n}_i}{\partial \mathbf{B}} \qquad i=1,2,3$$
In continuum mechanics, the tensors $\mathbf{n}_i \otimes  \mathbf{n}_i$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are referred to as symmetric second order tensors.

See here.

@TedBlack No, in that question they ask for $ \frac{\partial \mathbf{n}_i }{\partial \mathbf{B}} $

$ \frac{\partial \mathbf{n}_i  \mathbf{n}_i^\intercal}{\partial \mathbf{B}} = \frac{\partial{\bf n}_i }{\partial {\bf B}} {\bf n}_i^\intercal +{\bf n}_i \frac{\partial {\bf n}_i^\intercal}{\partial {\bf B}}$

$$\def\pdv#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\pdv{{\bf n}_k\otimes{\bf n}k}{B{rc}}
\sum_{l \neq k}
(\lambda_k-\lambda_l)^{-1}
n_{kc} n_{lr}
({\bf n}_l\otimes{\bf n}_k+{\bf n}_k\otimes{\bf n}_l).
$$

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\T{{\sf T}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\k{\otimes}  \def\ttt{3\times 3}
\def\e{{\large\varepsilon}}
\def\e{{\large e}}
\def\d{\delta}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\F{{\cal F}}
\def\E{{\cal E}}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\CR#1{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\mb#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\green#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\blue#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\RLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
\def\BLR#1{\blue{\LR{#1}}}
\def\GLR#1{\green{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Given the eigendecomposition of a real symmetric $\ttt$ matrix
$$\eqalign{
B &= NLN^\T,\q &L=\Diag{\l_1,\l_2,\l_3},
 \q &N=\mb{n_1&n_2&n_3},\q n_i^\T n_k=\d_{ik} \\
}$$
Choose an eigenpair of interest (e.g. $k=3$) and write down the corresponding eigenvalue equation, but drop the explicit  $k$-subscripts for ease of typing
$$\eqalign{
Bn = \l n  \qif \red{n^\T B = \l n^\T} \\
}$$
Calculate the (total) differential of this equation
$$\eqalign{
dB\,n + B\,dn &= \l\,dn + n\,d\l \\
}$$
Multiplying by $n^\T$ recovers the gradient of the eigenvalue
$$\eqalign{
n^\T dB\,n + \red{n^\T B}\,dn &= \l\,n^\T dn + \blue{n^\T n}\,d\l \\
n^\T dB\,n + \red{\l\,n^\T}dn &= \l\,n^\T dn + \blue{\o}\,d\l \\
n^\T dB\,n &= d\l \\
d\l &= nn^\T:dB \qiq \grad{\l}{B} = nn^\T \\
}$$
Back-substituting yields the gradient of the eigenvector
$$\eqalign{
dB\,n + B\,dn &= \l\,dn + n\,\red{d\l} \\
dB\,n + B\,dn &= \l\,dn + n\,\red{n^\T dB\,n} \\
\LR{I-nn^\T}dB\,n &= \LR{\l I-B}dn \\
\blue{\LR{\l I-B}^{\bf+}}\,dB\,n &= dn \\
\blue{G}\:dB\,n &= dn \\
dn &= \LR{G\k n}:dB \qiq \grad{n}{B} = G\k n \\
}$$

In the above, a colon denotes the double-dot product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^\T B} \\
B:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\sf Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^\T:A^\T \\
\LR{PQ}:B &= P:\LR{BQ^\T} \;=\; Q:\LR{P^\T B} \\
}$$
and $M^{\bf+}$ denotes the pseudoinverse of $M$. In particular
$$\eqalign{
\LR{\l I-B}^{\bf+}
 &= \bR{N\,\LR{\l I-L}N^\T}^{\bf+} \\
 &= N\,\LR{\l I-L}^{\bf+}N^\T \\
}$$
The matrix in parentheses is a rank-2 diagonal matrix whose $\LR{k,k}$ element is zero, so its pseudoinverse is particularly easy to calculate.
It is easy to see that $\LR{N^\T n_k}$ is equal to the $k^{th}$ cartesian basis vector $\e_k$ and therefore
$$\eqalign{
\LR{\l_kI-B}^{\bf+}n_k
 &= N\,\LR{\l_kI-L}^{\bf+}N^\T n_k \\
 &= N\,\LR{\l_kI-L}^{\bf+}\e_k \\
 &= 0 \\
}$$
For the final step, we'll need a couple of fourth-order isotropic tensors
$$\eqalign{
\E &= \grad BB &\qiq\E_{ijkl} = \grad{B_{ij}}{B_{kl}} = \d_{ik}\d_{jl} \\
\F &= \grad B{B^\T} &\qiq\F_{ijkl} = \grad{B_{ij}}{B_{kl}^\T} = \d_{il}\d_{jk} \\
}$$

The last step is to differentiate the dyadic product, which for vectors can be replaced by a transpose and a dot product
$$\eqalign{
\def\v{\cdot}
d\LR{n\k n}
 &= d\LR{n\v n^\T} \;=\; d\LR{nn^\T} \\ 
 &= dn\v n^\T \;+\; n\v dn^\T \\ 
 &= \LR{G\v dB\v n}\v n^\T \;+\; n\v \LR{G\v dB\v n}^\T \\ 
 &= G\v dB\v nn^\T \;+\; nn^\T\v dB^\T\v G \\ 
 &= \LR{G\v\E\v nn^\T}:dB \;+\; \LR{nn^\T\v\E\v G}:\F:dB \\ 
\grad{\LR{n\k n}}{B}
 &= \LR{G\v\E\v nn^\T} \;+\; \LR{nn^\T\v\E\v G}:\F \\ 
}$$
I assume that you are mainly interested in the case
where $\,dB^\T=dB$.
This simplifies the gradient to
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\LR{n\k n}}{B}
 &= \LR{G\v\E\v nn^\T} \;+\; \LR{nn^\T\v\E\v G} \\\\ 
}$$
If this tensor is too difficult to work with, you can resort to component-wise gradients
$$\eqalign{
\def\Bij{B_{ij}}
\def\Eij{E_{ij}}
\grad{\LR{n\k n}}{\Bij}
 &= \LR{G\v\Eij\v nn^\T} \;+\; \LR{nn^\T\v\Eij^\T\v G} \\ 
}$$
where $\Eij$ is a matrix whose $(i,j)$ component equals $\o$ and all other components are zero.

So there is no need to distinguish the cases with equal eigenvalues? The derivative equation is always of the above form?

It was high time greg appeared

@Greg Are you sure the fourth order tensors are correctly defined if $\mathbf B$ is a symmetric matrix?

@HugdeRoda  I used to have other ideas, but since reading this paper by Panda & Srinivasan, I don't think symmetric (or skew-symmetric) matrices require any special treatment. I love the Matrix Cookbook, but this is its worst section. Here's a post which sketches out what happens when you start with a symmetric $B$ but explore directions $dB$ which are skew-symmetric, or vice versa.

With respect to the final equation in your own post, the "no special treatment" logic of Panda & Srinivasan means that only the first term is needed, i.e. $$ \large \lambda_i \delta_{ac} \delta_{bd} $$ Then iff  $B$ is symmetric, the ${a,b}$ indices can be swapped without affecting the value. And since $nn^{\sf T}$ is symmetric the ${c,d}$ indices can likewise be swapped.

I'll ruminate on what you say. Meanwhile I edited my answer, it might interest what I say.

Your dyadic product is defined as
$$\boldsymbol n_i\otimes\boldsymbol n_i=n_{i\alpha}n_{i\beta}\,\boldsymbol e_\alpha\otimes\boldsymbol e_\beta$$
You can make use of
$$\dfrac{\partial B_{ab}}{\partial\boldsymbol n_i\otimes\boldsymbol n_i}\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol n_i\otimes\boldsymbol n_i}{\partial B_{ab}}={1\!\!1}_{3\times 3}\iff \dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol n_i\otimes\boldsymbol n_i}{\partial B_{ab}}=\left(\dfrac{\partial B_{ab}}{\partial\boldsymbol n_i\otimes\boldsymbol n_i}\right)^{-1}$$
$$\text{or }\ \dfrac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial n_{ic}n_{id}}\dfrac{\partial n_{ic}n_{id}}{\partial \mathbf B}={1\!\!1}_{3\times 3}\iff \dfrac{\partial n_{ic}n_{id}}{\partial \mathbf B}=\left(\dfrac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial n_{ic}n_{id}}\right)^{-1}$$
to compute those coefficients. Moreover,
$$\small\left(\dfrac{\partial B_{ab}}{\partial\boldsymbol n_i\otimes\boldsymbol n_i}\right)_{cd}=\left(\dfrac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial n_{ic}n_{id}}\right)_{ab}=\dfrac{\partial B_{ab}}{\partial n_{ic}n_{id}}=\sum_{j=1}^3\lambda_j\dfrac{\partial n_{ja}n_{jb}}{\partial n_{ic}n_{id}}=\lambda_i\dfrac{\partial n_{ia}n_{ib}}{\partial n_{ic}n_{id}}=\lambda_i(\delta_{ac}\delta_{bd}+\delta_{bc}\delta_{ad}-\delta_{ab}\delta_{cd}\delta_{ac})$$

$\mathbf{EDIT:}$ I fixed the last expression by multiplying $\delta_{ac}$ to the last term.
Furthermore, the thing I actually noticed is you can manually check that
$$\dfrac{\partial B_{ab}}{\partial\boldsymbol n_i\otimes\boldsymbol n_i}=\dfrac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial n_{ia}n_{ib}}$$
because of symmetry. Therefore, both expressions from the start are equivalent. The inconvenience here is that their determinant are all $0$ $\forall a,b$, meaning, in turn, that their inverses do not exist and hence this method is futile.

Can you comment how you come to the Kronecker deltas starting from $\dfrac{\partial n_{ia}n_{ib}}{\partial n_{ic}n_{id}}$ ? I know that something like $\dfrac{\partial n_{ia}}{\partial n_{ic}} = \delta_{ac}$ but I have never seen it if there is a product in the denominator.

Imagine $\boldsymbol n_i=(x_i,y_i)$. Then
$$\mathbf A=\boldsymbol n_i\otimes\boldsymbol n_i=\begin{pmatrix}
x_ix_i & y_ix_i\
x_iy_i & y_iy_i
\end{pmatrix}$$
This way,
$$\frac{\partial x_ix_i}{\partial\mathbf A}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\frac{\partial x_iy_i}{\partial\mathbf A}=\frac{\partial y_ix_i}{\partial\mathbf A}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\frac{\partial x_ix_i}{\partial\mathbf A}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
From this you can kinda deduce the expression I wrote. It also appears in the matrix cookbook

when differentiating a scalar wrt a symmetric matrix.
